# Change in Json response after upgrade to Json 2.25

Tags: java, json, jersey, jersey-2.0

After upgrading from Jersey 1.19 to Jersey 2.25, My json response is changed.

I have a property as below.

```
 @XmlElementWrapper(name = "items")
 @XmlElement(name = "contact")
 public List<Contact> items = new ArrayList<Contact>();
```

In Jersey 1.19

JSON

```
{
    "items": [
        {
        "id": "510651"
        }
    ]
}
```

Xml

```
<items>
    <contact>
        ..
        ..
    </contact>
</items>
```

After Upgrading to jersey 2.25, the xml seems to be fine, but there is issue with Json.

Json After upgrade

```
{
  "contact": [
        {
          "id": "510651"
        }
    ]
}
```

My Jersey Config is below

```
 public JerseyConfig() {
    packages("my.api");
    property(ServerProperties.WADL_FEATURE_DISABLE, true);
    register(RequestContextFilter.class);
    register(JacksonFeature.class);
    register(CacheControlFilter.class);
    register(GZipEncoder.class);
    register(new LoggingFeature(Logger.getLogger(LoggingFeature.DEFAULT_LOGGER_NAME), Level.INFO,
        LoggingFeature.Verbosity.PAYLOAD_TEXT, 10 * 1024));
    register(new AbstractBinder() {
      @Override
      public void configure() {
        bindFactory(LocaleFactory.class).to(Locale.class).in(RequestScoped.class);
      }
    });
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Jersey` uses `jackson` for generating `JSON` and in `jackson` 2.x this feature is changed. You can found more detail [here](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-module-jaxb-annotations/issues/13)

So, if you want to have similar behaviour, then you need to configure `USE_WRAPPER_NAME_AS_PROPERTY_NAME` `mapperFeature` -

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
mapper.configure(MapperFeature.USE_WRAPPER_NAME_AS_PROPERTY_NAME, true);
```

Now, this custom object mapper needs to be registered in `Jersey`. Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20563640/using-jackson-objectmapper-with-jersey) for details