# Unable to resolve any beans for Types [org.glassfish.jersey.message.filtering.spi.ObjectProvider<com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.FilterProvider>]

Tags: java, json, jackson, jersey-2.0, wildfly-8

trying to move from Moxy to Jackson json media provider for my Jersey web service and found couple of issues which I can't resolve so far:

first of all moxy was working fine for the same piece of code, but because we are using jackson everywhere in other projects I want to keep things consistent...
so I changed

1)  dependency in pom to

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
    <artifactId>jersey-media-json-jackson</artifactId>
    <version>${jersey.version}</version>
</dependency>
```

2) ResourceConfig regester

```
register(JacksonFeature.class)
```

but I started to get this exception when I run my webservice(basically it happens when I return from the web service method ):

```
Caused by: org.jboss.weld.exceptions.UnsatisfiedResolutionException: WELD-001308: Unable to resolve any beans for Types: [org.glassfish.jersey.message.filtering.spi.ObjectProvider<com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.FilterProvider>]; Bindings: [QualifierInstance{annotationClass=interface javax.enterprise.inject.Default, values={}, hashCode=48147280}]
    at org.jboss.weld.manager.BeanManagerImpl.getBean(BeanManagerImpl.java:815) [weld-core-impl-2.1.2.Final.jar:2014-01-09 09:23]
    at org.jboss.weld.bean.builtin.InstanceImpl.get(InstanceImpl.java:75) [weld-core-impl-2.1.2.Final.jar:2014-01-09 09:23]
    at org.glassfish.jersey.jackson.internal.FilteringJacksonJaxbJsonProvider.writeTo(FilteringJacksonJaxbJsonProvider.java:130) [jersey-media-json-jackson-2.17.jar:]
    at org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.WriterInterceptorExecutor$TerminalWriterInterceptor.invokeWriteTo(WriterInterceptorExecutor.java:265) [jersey-common-2.17.jar:]
    at org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.WriterInterceptorExecutor$TerminalWriterInterceptor.aroundWriteTo(WriterInterceptorExecutor.java:250) [jersey-common-2.17.jar:]
    at org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.WriterInterceptorExecutor.proceed(WriterInterceptorExecutor.java:162) [jersey-common-2.17.jar:]
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.internal.JsonWithPaddingInterceptor.aroundWriteTo(JsonWithPaddingInterceptor.java:106) [jersey-server-2.17.jar:]
    at org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.WriterInterceptorExecutor.proceed(WriterInterceptorExecutor.java:162) [jersey-common-2.17.jar:]
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.internal.MappableExceptionWrapperInterceptor.aroundWriteTo(MappableExceptionWrapperInterceptor.java:86) [jersey-server-2.17.jar:]
    at org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.WriterInterceptorExecutor.proceed(WriterInterceptorExecutor.java:162) [jersey-common-2.17.jar:]
    at org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.MessageBodyFactory.writeTo(MessageBodyFactory.java:1128) [jersey-common-2.17.jar:]
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime$Responder.writeResponse(ServerRuntime.java:664) [jersey-server-2.17.jar:]
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime$Responder.processResponse(ServerRuntime.java:421) [jersey-server-2.17.jar:]
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime$Responder.process(ServerRuntime.java:411) [jersey-server-2.17.jar:]
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime$2.run(ServerRuntime.java:308) [jersey-server-2.17.jar:]
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:271) [jersey-common-2.17.jar:]
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:267) [jersey-common-2.17.jar:]
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:315) [jersey-common-2.17.jar:]
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:297) [jersey-common-2.17.jar:]
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:267) [jersey-common-2.17.jar:]
    at org.glassfish.jersey.process.internal.RequestScope.runInScope(RequestScope.java:317) [jersey-common-2.17.jar:]
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime.process(ServerRuntime.java:288) [jersey-server-2.17.jar:]
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.handle(ApplicationHandler.java:1110) [jersey-server-2.17.jar:]
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.service(WebComponent.java:401) [jersey-container-servlet-core-2.17.jar:]
    ... 29 more
```

yea...and apparently we use WildFly as an application server if it matters .

So if someone could point me where the problem might be, that's would be awesome.

Cheers!

Comment: Try and use `jackson-jaxrs-json-provider-2.4.0` instead. Register the package `com.fasterxml.jackson.jaxrs.json`. See what happens.

Comment: yeap...fasterxml just started to work ...even 2.5.3

Comment: I think what the problem is is that Jersey is using it own Jackson provider, for the purpose of supporting it's entity filtering feature. There seems to be some injection there that causes weld to kick in. Weld can't find the dependencies. Which is odd, as Jersey use's it's HK2 dependency injector. I don't know if this will cause a problem further down the line. I've never tried to use Jersey with JBoss. You can look at [the documentation](https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/cdi.support.html) for cdi support, if it does become a problem.

Comment: yea...I'm using gf-cdi in my project for DI. Dunno if it was causing a problem or smth else. Also I found this answer very helpful if someone struggling with the same issue http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18872931/custom-objectmapper-with-jersey-2-2-and-jackson-2-1    @peeskillet, maybe you make your answer so I could accept it

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem seems to be occurring in the `FilteringJacksonJaxbJsonProvider`, which is Jersey own Jackson provider, for it's support for it [Entity Data Filtering](https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/entity-filtering.html). Seems there is some injection (invoking Weld) going on that causes it to fail. If you don't need the entity data filtering feature, you could get rid of the `jersey-media-json-jackson` and instead use

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.jaxrs</groupId>
  <artifactId>jackson-jaxrs-json-provider</artifactId>
  <version>${jackson2.version}</version>
</dependency>
// as of now ${jackson2.version} == 2.5.3
```

As for the Weld problem, I am not sure if it will cause a problem for you in the future, so I would not consider changing the Jackson dependency being a solution, rather a work-around.

You said in your comments you are using `gf-cdi`. Maybe that is the problem. That artifact is no longer produced after Jersey 2.14 (you're using Jersey 2.17). The CDI support module has changed. You can see [27.3.1. Release 2.15 Highlights](https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/migration.html#mig-2.15). It mentions some things about the CDI support dependencies.

> CDI support improvement caused breaking changes for those users directly referring to the following CDI supporting Jersey module in maven:
>
> ```
> <dependency>
>      <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.containers.glassfish</groupId>
>      <artifactId>jersey-gf-cdi</artifactId>
>      <version>${pre-2.15-version}</version>
>  </dependency>
> ```
>
> The above dependency needs to be replaced with:
>
> ```
> <dependency>
>      <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.ext.cdi</groupId>
>      <artifactId>jersey-cdi1x</artifactId>
>      <version>2.17</version>
> </dependency>
> ```
>
> The following needs to be included in addition if you want to leverage CDI JTA support:
>
> ```
> <dependency>
>      <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.ext.cdi</groupId>
>      <artifactId>jersey-cdi1x-transaction</artifactId>
>      <version>2.17</version>
> </dependency>
> ```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve this by simply putting "Accept: application/xml" in the request. I also used @Consumes annotation as shown in the screenshot. [image]

[image]