# WELD-001408: Unsatisfied dependencies for type ObjectMapper with qualifiers @Default at

Tags: java-ee-7, wildfly-10, fasterxml, jackson2, jackson-databind

I try to inject an ObjectMapper using fasterXML jackson like this:

```
@Inject
private ObjectMapper objectMapper;
```

but i have the next error when i try to deploy the war file:

> org.jboss.weld.exceptions.DeploymentException: WELD-001408:
>   Unsatisfied dependencies for type **ObjectMapper** with qualifiers
>   **@Default**

This are my dependencies:

```
    <!-- the core, which includes Streaming API, shared low-level abstractions (but NOT data-binding) -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
        <version>${jackson-2-version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- Just the annotations; use this dependency if you want to attach annotations
         to classes without connecting them to the code. -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-annotations</artifactId>
        <version>${jackson-2-version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- databinding; ObjectMapper, JsonNode and related classes are here -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
        <version>${jackson-2-version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- jackson-dataformat-yaml: Support for reading and writing YAML-encoded data via Jackson abstractions -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-dataformat-yaml</artifactId>
        <version>${jackson-2-version}</version>
    </dependency>
```

What i did wrong?

Comment: Is the `ObjectMapper` injectable? I don't think it's annotated with any qualifying CDI annotations.

Comment: in that case it's necessary create a provider method?

Comment: To be honest I don't know the case as I don't know the library all that well, but when I looked at the source for `ObjectMapper` it didn't have any qualifying CDI annotations.

Comment: I found the solution based on this thread http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18872931/custom-objectmapper-with-jersey-2-2-and-jackson-2-1

Answer (score 0):

I am making the assumption you need the `ObjectMapper` to do some configuration on it. For this you can use:

```
@Provider
public class ObjectMapperContextResolver implements ContextResolver<ObjectMapper> {

    private final ObjectMapper mapper;

    public ObjectMapperContextResolver() {
        mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        // Do some configuration here
    }

    @Override
    public ObjectMapper getContext(Class<?> type) {
        return mapper;
    }

}
```