# Jackson's @JsonAppend with default value

Tags: java, json, serialization, jackson, kotlin

guys! I am developing a web application and I decided to use Jackson as my JSON processing framework.

In request data that I am willing to send; let's say the POJO looks like this:

```
data class JSONEnvelope(
        @JsonProperty("obj1")
        val obj1: Obj1,

        @JsonProperty("obj2")
        val obj2: Obj2)
```

which get serialized like this:

```
{
    "obj1":{...},
    "obj2":{...}
}
```

but I need to add some metadata to that object, let's say fields `meta1` and `meta`. I thought that `@JsonAppend` would solve my problem, but I am using Jackson together with Jersey, so I am not serializing objects manually, so I cannot use `writer.withAttribute("...", ...)`.

I am aware of [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14714328/jackson-how-to-add-custom-property-to-the-json-without-modifying-the-pojo), but there is no answer that kinda satisfy my needs, because I think, that writing a custom serializer is a bit overkill for this, moreover if I do not have a mechanism to "serialize the rest of the original object". I'd be glad for any ideas

Comment: In this context, what do you mean by "metadata"? Could it be implemented as simple computed properties that Jackson maps in the normal way?

Comment: @PaulHicks By metadata I mean additional fields, because this object is the root one and remote API requires to have, for example, the JSON version specified, so I'd like to add field `"jsonrpc":"2.0"`. Yes, I can add it as a field to the class, but I think that it does not belong there as that information is not the part of the entity's state. 
I don't know what you mean by computed properties

Comment: Computed properties are simply ones with no setter (or where the setter does nothing); for example, `val jsonrpc = "2.0"` or `var time = Date().getTime()`.  Some properties would be suitable for an envelope class. If you don't to modify `JSONEnvelope`, then JsonAppend does seem like the best option. If you can't modify the ObjectWriter after calling `ObjectMapper.writerFor` then you'll have to do it beforehand, by overriding the `writerFor` method in an ObjectMapper that you provide using `@Provider`.

Comment: @PaulHicks Thank you for clearance! If you convert a comment to an answer, I'd be glad to accept it. I didn't even think about overriding `writeFor`, Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution in [the answer you cited](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42455398/3195526), which adds a mixIn to a the ObjectMapper then uses the ObjectWriter to configure it, is a good solution.

For Jersey, which calls `ObjectMapper.writerFor` and therefore prevents you from calling withAttribute in order to configure the ObjectWriter, one alternative is to add the attribute to the ObjectWriter *before* returning it from writerFor. I suggest subclassing ObjectMapper and overriding the various writerFor methods, adding the necessary attribute at that point. You can then get Jersey to use that ObjectMapper by registering it as a JAX-RS Provider: see the various annotations in `javax.ws.rs` to get started on this. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30082203/3195526) gives an example of what to do.